# Enterprise app installing but immediatelly dissapears

Tags: ios, enterprise

I'm trying to install my enterprise app but after the alert on the webpage that says to install the app the icon just changes to the one selected on my device and after this dissappears.

I search and found that this could be caused by a different bundle id on the manifest and the app but this not seems to be the problem.
I deleted and re make the certificates and provisioning profiles to the distribution on house.

And of course I have a enterprise developer account.

When I try to install the app this is the console log of the device but i thing that doesn't gives significant information:

```
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x137985e30> com.company.product <(null) *Not found in database*>
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/2472169525513059198.app" type Placeholder (LSInstallType = 1) requested by itunesstored (pid 108)
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller _extractPackageWithError:]: Incoming install at /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.OIMMYz/extracted/2472169525513059198.app had class 3; changing to class 4
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.company.product; Version=2.8, ShortVersion=(null)>
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.company.product at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7159033A-3110-4210-9C62-A726D8A1165E
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.company.product at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0941164D-1979-427A-8F73-FE9B1E963F9D
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.01s; Overall: 0.11s
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1379819c0> com.company.product (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0941164D-1979-427A-8F73-FE9B1E963F9D/2472169525513059198.app> withPhase:3
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.company.product.InstallingPlaceholder - <NSProgress: 0x1366f76f0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   called, removing progress from cache
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for <LSApplicationProxy: 0x1379819c0> com.company.product (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0941164D-1979-427A-8F73-FE9B1E963F9D/2472169525513059198.app> with icons
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e087000 -[MIClientConnection installPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/2472169525513059198.app" type Placeholder (LSInstallType = 1) requested by itunesstored (pid 108)
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller _extractPackageWithError:]: Incoming install at /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.JdOYKB/extracted/2472169525513059198.app had class 3; changing to class 4
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.company.product; Version=2.8, ShortVersion=(null)>
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.company.product is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C5862B48-66D9-4C43-8062-7176554FA163
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.company.product at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/24EC78B5-0119-4D8B-AC5E-D600534DC00C
Jan 15 16:36:52 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Install Successful; Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Preflight/Patch: 0.00s, Verifying: 0.00s; Overall: 0.09s
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio nsurlsessiond[112] <Error>: Task 15 for client <CFString 0x19ca56f00 [0x1a0e65b68]>{contents = "com.apple.itunesstored"} completed with error - code: -999
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:<LSApplicationProxy: 0x1367841b0> com.company.product (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/24EC78B5-0119-4D8B-AC5E-D600534DC00C/2472169525513059198.app> withPhase:0
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio lsd[82] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: 0x12f56c5c0> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100   to 0
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling placeholder for app <LSApplicationProxy: 0x13797bb60> com.company.product (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/24EC78B5-0119-4D8B-AC5E-D600534DC00C/2472169525513059198.app>
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Uninstalling app <LSApplicationProxy: 0x13797bb60> com.company.product (Placeholder) <file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/24EC78B5-0119-4D8B-AC5E-D600534DC00C/2472169525513059198.app>
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIClientConnection uninstallIdentifiers:withOptions:completion:]: Uninstall requested by itunesstored (pid 108) for identifier com.company.product with options: {
    }
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio lsd[82] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation ended for app com.company.product
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio lsd[82] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In subscribeBlock: could not find parent progress for com.company.product, it may have been removed
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio lsd[82] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In subscribeBlock: could not find parent progress for com.company.product, it may have been removed
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio lsd[82] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In subscribeBlock: could not find parent progress for com.company.product, it may have been removed
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio lsd[82] <Warning>: LSInstallProgress: In subscribeBlock: could not find parent progress for com.company.product, it may have been removed
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIUninstaller _uninstallBundleWithIdentifier:error:]: Uninstalling identifier com.company.product
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIUninstallNotifier performRemovalWithCompletionBlock:]: Destroying container with identifier com.company.product at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/24EC78B5-0119-4D8B-AC5E-D600534DC00C
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio installd[46] <Notice>: 0x16e12f000 -[MIUninstallNotifier performRemovalWithCompletionBlock:]: Destroying container with identifier com.company.product at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C5862B48-66D9-4C43-8062-7176554FA163
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServies: No app bundle to remove for com.company.product
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio lsd[82] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Jan 15 16:36:53 iPhone-de-Sergio itunesstored[108] <Warning>: LaunchServices: clearing created progress for com.company.product
```

What I'm making wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure, you've tried rebooting the device? The installer can be quite flaky sometimes. Also, you don't have any instance of the same app (identified by the same bundle ID) already installed or being installed on the same device?

Comment: I've try to reinstall but still doesn't work. I have the plist manifest file and the IPA served without SSL, this can cause that problem?

Comment: Going through your logs, wouldn't your bundle ID match the bundle ID of an app published in the App Store (or maybe even created in iTunes Connect or Member Center)? For security reasons it's possible it doesn't allow this.

Comment: for privacy reasons I've replaced the string of the bundle of this logs id for a generic one... complementing my last update: I have an old  IPA working without SSL.

Comment: I understood that. What I mean is that the logs say `Uninstall requested by itunesstored (pid 108) for identifier...`, so I would guess it checks something with the iTunes Store, and it may be that you have a bundle ID conflict.

Comment: So, how did things turn out? Also, have you tried upgrading to iOS 9.2.1? There's a fix for a related issue, not sure if that actually affected you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the next mistakes, maybe for someone are useful:

1. Call all the links on the plist and html with https (And use a server that support that too). I has the mistake that mix http and https addresses on the href.
2. Ensure that the folder where the IPA is stored has permissions to download: I checked that on the root folder I can 'see' the file. on the folder when I'm publishing the app don't.